# Scoped storage : Create/ Modify and Delete file in documents folder, contentResolver?.query Uri returns null

Tags: android, kotlin

**Requirement:** Need to write application log content to a file every day for issue trouble shooting .The file need to create everyday and append the current date to file name. This already did in the sdcard/data/data/ folder and is working fine. But from android 11 onwards we cant't able to access app specific folder through other application like Airwatch.  To support this I used Scoped storage and writing log in document shared folder. Here I am facing the below issue.

Below code I used for scoped storage, but every file write creating new files like txt, .txt(1), .txt(3), etc.
Instead of that need to append the content to existing file content.  Anyone faced this issue and resolved? If yes can you please help me to troubleshoot the issue from the below code snippet?

```
const val FOLDER = "/Test/TestDocuments/"
const val FILE_NAME = "Log"

fun Context.createFolder() {
try {
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + FOLDER
    )
    val uri: Uri? = getContentResolver().insert(
        MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
        values
    )
    Toast.makeText(this, "" +
            "$uri File created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
} catch (e: IOException) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Fail to create file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
 }
}

fun Context.findAndOverwriteFile(){
  val contentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")

  val selection = MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH + "=?"

  val selectionArgs =
    arrayOf(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + FOLDER) 


val cursor = contentResolver.query(contentUri, null, selection, selectionArgs, null)

var uri: Uri? = null

if (cursor!!.count == 0) {
    Toast.makeText(
        this,
        "No file found in \"" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/Test/TestDocuments/\"",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    ).show()
   createNewFileAndWrite()
} else {
    while (cursor!!.moveToNext()) {
        val fileName =
            cursor!!.getString(cursor!!.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME))
        if (fileName == "$FILE_NAME${getPreferenceData(LOGGER_UNIQUE_ID)}.txt") {                          //must include extension
            val id = cursor!!.getLong(cursor!!.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID))
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(contentUri, id)
            break
        }
    }
    if (uri == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "\"Log.txt\" not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    } else {
        try {
            val outputStream =
                contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri, "rwt") //overwrite mode, see below
            outputStream!!.write("This is overwritten data。\n New Text".toByteArray())
            outputStream!!.close()
            Toast.makeText(this, "File written successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fail to write file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
   }
 }

fun Context.createNewFileAndWrite(){
 val values = ContentValues()
 values.put(
     MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
     "$FILE_NAME${getPreferenceData(LOGGER_UNIQUE_ID)}"
 ) 
 values.put(
     MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,
     "text/plain"
 ) 
values.put(
    MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + FOLDER
) 
val uri: Uri? = getContentResolver().insert(
    MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
    values
)
val outputStream: OutputStream? = uri?.let { 
contentResolver.openOutputStream(it) }
outputStream?.write("This is menu category data.".toByteArray())
outputStream?.close()
Toast.makeText(this, "" +
        "$uri File created successfully", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

**getPreferenceData(LOGGER_UNIQUE_ID)**: MEthod will return current date in millisecond and save in preference to identify the log file uniquely for a day.

Comment: If you use the MediaStore to create files then you do not need to create a folder first. Just create the file with RELATIVE_PATH indicating the folders and they will be created. To be honest i did not know that one can only create a folder using MediaStore. I will try that later.

Comment: In general: if you want to append(to an existing file) then use the uri you got at first insert(). Or search for the file to get its uri.

Comment: `appName.getSharedFilePath()` If appName is a String then i do not understand this method.